# Select, insert and center a photo in the merged cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a R&D baker and making a recipe template for my team,
In the template there's the photo, but I need to easily allow them to click a button that will open a file selector for the photo, then center that photo in the merged cells.  I'm not really good at doing this..

[image]

```
Sub InsertPhotoMacro()
    Dim photoNameAndPath As Variant
    Dim photo As Picture

    photoNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Photo to Insert")
    
    If photoNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set photo = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(photoNameAndPath)
    
    With photo
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("E23").Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("E23").Top
        .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("F29").Width
        .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("F29").Height
        .Placement = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

To **Select**, **Insert** and **Fill** the cell, try this. Just centering it is not enough. What if the image is bigger than the merged cell?

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertPhotoMacro()
    Dim photoNameAndPath As Variant
    Dim photo As Picture
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MrdgCell As Range
    
    '~~> This is your worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    '~~> And this is the merged cell
    Set MrdgCell = ws.Range("E23")
    
    photoNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Photo to Insert")
    
    If photoNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set photo = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(photoNameAndPath)
    
    With photo
        '~~> Disable lock aspect ratio that we can freely transform
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        
        .Left = MrdgCell.Left
        .Top = MrdgCell.Top
        
        '~~> This is the total merged area height and width
        .Height = MrdgCell.MergeArea.Height
        .Width = MrdgCell.MergeArea.Width
    End With
End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER (SCENARIO 1)**

[image]

And if you do not want to **Fill** but just **Center** the image then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertPhotoMacro()
    Dim photoNameAndPath As Variant
    Dim photo As Picture
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MrdgCell As Range
    
    '~~> This is your worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    '~~> And this is the merged cell
    Set MrdgCell = ws.Range("E23")
    
    photoNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Photo to Insert")
    
    If photoNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set photo = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(photoNameAndPath)
    
    With photo
        .Left = MrdgCell.Left + (MrdgCell.MergeArea.Width - .Width) / 2
        .Top = MrdgCell.Top + (MrdgCell.MergeArea.Height - .Height) / 2
    End With
End Sub
```

**AFTER (SCENARIO 2)**

[image]

**LOGIC**

Whatever option you use, understand how to arrive at the correct co-ordinates/dimensions

[image]

No need to use the start and the end cell. You can refer to the complete merged cell using `.MergeArea.Width` and `.MergeArea.Height`

So if you want to center, the calculation for `LEFT` will be

```
MERGED CELL LEFT + (MERGED CELL WIDTH - IMAGE WIDTH) / 2
```

Similarly for `TOP`, it will be

```
MERGED CELL TOP + (MERGED CELL HEIGHT - IMAGE HEIGHT) / 2
```